# SSRS - How to pull previous Friday with SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I'm needing help to pull the previous business days and excluding the weekends in SSRS.  I use the following code, however this code doesn't look past the weekends.

**Here's the code I normally use:**

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
, Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2
,True, -1)
, Today())
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to write an SSRS expression to look past the weekends and pull only business days?

Comment: Do you mean you want the previous M-F business day of a given day?

Comment: No, I need to pull previous Friday and have it set in the report.  Every Monday we need to pull Friday data.

Comment: What do you mean by the code doesn't look past the weekends? Can you edit your question to include what you expect for a date range when the report is run on a Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wed., etc.?

Comment: So, I have reports that the business runs every Monday, but they need to pull the data as of the previous bizday Friday.  I have the expression set in the parameter to pull the previous business day, but it's only brings back Sunday (from the code above).  Example:  Monday 4/10...I need the expression to pull 4/7(prev biz day)  Is there a way to write the expression to skip the weekends and only pull the previous biz day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued exploring this and worked with others here...This is what we came up with to look to the previous business day and exclude the weekends when pulling the report on a Monday.  This expression would be added to the date parameter.

```
=Switch(WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Wednesday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -2)    , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Thursday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -2)    , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Friday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -2)    , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Saturday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -2)   , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Sunday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -3)    , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Monday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -4)    , Today()),

    WeekdayName(DatePart("w", Today)) = "Tuesday",DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 2, -3
 ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today()) = 1, -2,True, -2)    , Today())

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have a different first day of the week set (depending on region or how the server is configured).  Explicitly setting `FirstDayOfWeek` in the `DatePart` function should give consistent results regardless of this setting:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day
    , Switch(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today(), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday) = 2, -3
        ,DatePart(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today(), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday) = 1, -2
        ,True, -1)
    , Today())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to default a date parameter to Friday when the report runs on a Monday (otherwise the default is the prior day), try this:

`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, IIf(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Today) = 2, -3, -1), Today)`

This may be all you really need.

The following expression can be used to default a date parameter to the prior Friday, no matter what day of the week the report is run on. This can have some value for weekly reporting.

`=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Today), 0, 0)), Today)`

Answer (score 0):

This expression will also pull the previous business day, which I've been using lately.  Just need to update your Date Parameter with this code.

```
=DateAdd("d",Switch(DatePart("w", Today) = 2,-3,DatePart("w", Today) = 1,-2,True,-1),Today)
```